# How to change bitmap image runtime based on condition and set on canvas?

Tags: android-layout

I have nine rectangles drawn on canvas and I had set image on it through bitmap by decoding it from resources. I am generating random numbers between 1 to 10 and set it to text view.
When user moves to rectangle based on number displaying in text view the image of that particular rectangle should be changed

```
if(textview.getText().toString()==1)
{    
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapHolo,null,rect[i],null);    
}
else
{       
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapRectangle,null,rect[i],null);    
}
```